# Form action url not working in yii2 framework

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['action'=>'SiteController/actionUploadImage','method'=>'post','enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput() ?>

<button>Submit</button>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

This is my form, in inspect element action not showing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 main problems in your code.

The first one is, that the array with url should have format of `['controller-id/action-id']` but your url has format `['ControllerClass/actionMethod']`.

The second one is the position of `action` in your array. As **Sfili_81** mentioned in his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58797242/11977068

So the correct code should look like:

```php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['site/upload-image'],
    'method' => 'post',
    'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
]);
```

Also since yii 2.0.8 there is no need to explicitily use  `enctype` option if you are using ActiveForm. Calling `$form->field(...)->fileInput()` will ensure the correct enctype.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write action outside the options like this:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => ['SiteController/actionUploadImage'],'method' => 'post']) ?>
```

[[documentation]](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activeform#$method-detail)